# Security System Preference won't open on Macos 10.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, crash, system-preferences

When I try to open the Security preference pane on my iMac running Mac OS 10.6.6, it says "loading..." and it never opens. I get this in the console:

```
3/5/11 4:16:56 PM   System Preferences[724] Could not connect the action resetLocationWarningsSheetOk: to target of class AppleSecurity_Pref
3/5/11 4:16:56 PM   System Preferences[724] Could not connect the action resetLocationWarningsSheetCancel: to target of class AppleSecurity_Pref
3/5/11 4:16:56 PM   System Preferences[724] *** -[NSCFDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil value at objects[0] (key: NSFont)
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer to prevent the question from being bumped to the front page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling, I found [the answer here](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10121597#10120608). The fix was to remove duplicate fonts using FontBook.